# Stamp id list 2 to list 1 sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have been created 2 list, list 1 and list 2. How can i stamp id in list 2 to list 1.. like relationship between list 1 and list 2.. in list 1 we can see form list 1 and related item in list 2. Impossible to do that or not?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup column in list 1 for list 2 this will create a relationship between the two lists, you can choose the columns that you want to display from list 2 in list as well.

Just like you add column you can add the lookup column by going to add column in list settings and choose the type as lookup column.

Step by step guide is available in MSDN
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-lookup-fields